# Avoid disk usage as an intermediate step for Zip Compression in C#

Tags: c#, .net, diskspace, system.io.compression

The official C# documentation states, that `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()` creates a zipfile on the disk, as an intermediate step. However I need my system to run on devices where disk space is critical.  Can I somehow just create the Zipfile in memory?

Answer (score 6):

.NET 8 adds exactly what you are looking or!!
It adds new overloads as documented in [Stream-based ZipFile methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8#stream-based-zipfile-methods):

> .NET 8 includes new overloads of `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` that allow you to collect all the files included in a directory and zip them, then store the resulting zip file into the provided stream. Similarly, new `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` overloads let you provide a stream containing a zipped file and extract its contents into the filesystem. These are the new overloads:

```
namespace System.IO.Compression;

public static partial class ZipFile
{
    public static void CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, Stream destination);
    public static void CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, Stream destination, CompressionLevel compressionLevel, bool includeBaseDirectory);
    public static void CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, Stream destination, CompressionLevel compressionLevel, bool includeBaseDirectory, Encoding? entryNameEncoding);

    public static void ExtractToDirectory(Stream source, string destinationDirectoryName) { }
    public static void ExtractToDirectory(Stream source, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwriteFiles) { }
    public static void ExtractToDirectory(Stream source, string destinationDirectoryName, Encoding? entryNameEncoding) { }
    public static void ExtractToDirectory(Stream source, string destinationDirectoryName, Encoding? entryNameEncoding, bool overwriteFiles) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While .NET 8 adds `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` overloads that allow writing to a stream directly, you don't have to wait for that to come out to do that.

Instead, you can simply create a `ZipArchive` with your stream and a `ZipArchiveMode` of `Create`, and then add entries to it:

```
public static void CreateZipArchive(string sourceDirectory, Stream destination)
{
    using var archive = new ZipArchive(destination, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var entryName = Path.GetRelativePath(sourceDirectory, file).Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '/');
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, entryName);
    }
}
```

Use a `MemoryStream` to write to memory.